# Prove that $L=\big\{\langle G\rangle \mid G\text{ is a CFG over }\Sigma=\{0,1\}\text{ and }1^* \cap L(G)\ne\varnothing\big\}$ is decidable.

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar, decidability

How to prove that $L = \big\{\langle G\rangle \mid G \text { is a CFG over } \Sigma = \{0,1\} \text { and } 1^* \cap L(G) \ne \varnothing\big\}$ is decidable? I know I am supposed to prove that it is decidable or not $ L $ contains some string of the language $1^*$ and I know that CFLs are not closed under intersection and that $E_{TM}$ is not decidable but I am having trouble constructing the proof knowing this. If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Please repeat the question in the body. Also, as it stands, it isn't even parsable

Comment: How would I make the questions parsable?

Comment: Shouldn't the claim have the same number of "$\{$" and "$\}$", for example?

Comment: Yes, I mistyped that. I will correct that.

Comment: Are you asking how to prove that $L$ is decidable?

Comment: Yes, I had that in the body but not the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. The intersection of a context-free language with a regular language is context-free.

Comment: I don't understand your comment and even less your vote for deletion. The OP clearly states "If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it". This is exactly what I did by giving a hint.

Comment: Thank you. I have figured it out.